# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'. Import modules from another directory without sys.path and execute them from existing directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

Even though it is a common question, I believe I have a weird situation

```
MAIN
| --src
     | -- data 
            | -- __init__.py
            | -- operation.py
| tests
          | __init__.py
          | test_file.py
| examples
          | __init__.py
          | example.py
```

The contents of test_file.py and example.py are as follows:

```
from src.data.operation import *
```

I execute the following command from the powershell by navigating inside the tests folder:

```
python -m pytest -v test_file.py
```

The test file runs fine without giving any errors.

Now I execute the following command from the powershell by navigating inside the examples folder:

```
python -m example.py
```

This throws me the module error. Even though tests and examples are in the same hierarchy as src, I get the module error only when I execute the example.py file by navigating inside the examples folder. It would be great if someone could explain the logic behind this and what would be the best way to execute example.py in a windows system that does not involve sys.path?

Comment: What is the import statement in example.py?

Comment: Both are the same. I have made the necessary edits

Comment: try executing like python -m examples\example.py

Comment: Tried it from examples folder. Did not work

Comment: Is `examples` supposed to be a package?  Who would `from examples import` anything?

Comment: @DavisHerring examples need not be a package. Would it work differently if examples were not a package?

Comment: @Aditya: Failing to import a module via running a script that is otherwise a module inside a package is one of the most common Python issues asked about here.  I wanted to know if that was the problem here, and I thought it strange that you were using `-m` with a file (rather than a module) name.

Comment: @DavisHerring I have read similar questions in stack overflow here. But can you please explain how does the test_file.py work in that case? I use python -m pytest test_file.py from the tests folder. Does pytest somehow resolve the module not found error? How is it different from the examples folder?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to import without appending sys.path. By default, Python looks for its modules and packages in $PYTHONPATH. When you import something in the module it 1st searches for a built-in module with that name, it then searches for a file or folder in the list of directories given by the variable sys.path.

To successfully import from src, add these lines on top of the example.py

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "PATH_TO_THE_MAIN_FOLDER")
```

run the module from inside examples folder:

```
python -m example
```

Comment: Then how am I able to run the test cases from inside the tests folder without appending the path to sys.path? Since examples and tests are in the same level as src, shouldn't the behavior be same?

Comment: python -m test_file.py should throw a similar error

Comment: so using pytest along with python -m resolves the module not found error? I still don't understand how python -m pytest test_file.py works. shouldn't it throw the same error?